# Android Studio Properties Tab

Tags: android, xml, kotlin

I am trying to edit the properties of a button in Android Studio using the Design tab. I can usually see the names of each of the properties such as backgrounColor, etc. I don't know what I did, but now I can not see the names. I only see this. [image]